# How to scrape html value with id

Tags: php, html

I want to scrape information from an external page.
I know the id of that tag.
How to get the value from it ?

```
<span id="priceblock_ourprice" class="a-size-medium a-color-price"><span class="currencyINR">&nbsp;&nbsp;</span> 469.00</span>
```

How can I get the value 469 ?

Comment: Whats the external page

Comment: it is an e-commerce site.

Comment: are you able to access this span, and only need to get the value from it? or you don't know how to access this span from external site?

Comment: I don't know how to access the span as well.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you only need to get text from the span, use jQuery

```js
var value = $("#priceblock_ourprice").text();
console.log(value);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="priceblock_ourprice" class="a-size-medium a-color-price"><span class="currencyINR">&nbsp;&nbsp;</span> 469.00</span>
```